# How to drag an element from one div and drop it in another div

Tags: jquery

I have created 2 divs and I want to drag an item from one of the divs and drop it in the other div.

How do I implement the  functions `draggable()` and `droppable()`?

Comment: Have you searched for tutorials? I bet there are plenty of them.

Comment: The main demo page shows how to do this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/ You should check out the library's own demos, that's just about always the best place to start.

Comment: @Felix & @Nick are right. Best thing to do is dig in and just try examples. You'll learn more that way. When you get stuck with some specific trouble, come back here and post a question that includes the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

I found "A more elaborated jQuery Drag & Drop (with cloning)"
http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/

He also setup a js bin http://jsbin.com/opifo4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little tutorial to get you started: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210210233758/http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/02/21/119882.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI plugin has both draggable and droppable functionality. Check out here for demo material: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/.

Grz, Kris.